# Is there a "good" way to get normalised rows of data from ES nested aggregations?

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Elasticsearch nested aggregations allow you to effectively group by multiple fields. But what it returns is buckets which are nested for each field you group by.

What I need is an array of objects for each group combination.

My query:

```
{
  index : 'stats',
  type  : 'click',
  size  : 0,
  body  : {
    aggs : {
      publisher : {
        terms : {
          field : 'publisherData.id'
        },
        aggs  : {
          advertiser : {
            terms : {
              field : 'advertiserData.id'
            },
            aggs  : {
              country : {
                terms : {
                  field : 'request.location.country.iso_code'
                },
                aggs  : {
                  revenue : {
                    sum : {
                      field : 'revenueData.data.USD'
                    }
                  },
                  cost    : {
                    sum : {
                      field : 'costData.data.USD'
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result, limited to one entry per field. Normally there would be more so all combinations of nested fields would have to be mapped to an array for display in a table.

```
{
  "took": 562,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 4812178,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "publisher": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 3114671,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": 4,
          "doc_count": 1697507,
          "advertiser": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 555390,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": 5,
                "doc_count": 1142117,
                "country": {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 13807,
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 544585,
                  "buckets": [
                    {
                      "key": "us",
                      "doc_count": 424137,
                      "revenue": {
                        "value": 772282
                      },
                      "cost": {
                        "value": 53698.84903321415
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

What I need (normally there would be multiple objects here, one for each combination of nested fields) :

```
[{
    publisher:4,
    advertiser:5,
    country:'us',
    cost:53698.84903321415,
    revenue:772282
}]
```

What's the best way to get this result from the above nested structure or even better and if possible, from elasticsearch itself.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In plain Javascript, you could use an iterative and recursive approach - but I suggest to use some feature of ES for getting the wanted result.

```js
function getValues(object) {

    function iter(o, p) {
        var add = false;
        Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
            if (['key', 'doc_count'].indexOf(k) !== -1) {
                return;
            }
            if (Array.isArray(o[k].buckets)) {
                o[k].buckets.forEach(function (a) {
                    iter(a, p.concat([[k, a.key]]));
                });
                return;
            }
            add = true;
            p.push([k, o[k].value]);
        });
        add && result.push(Object.assign({}, ...p.map(a => ({[a[0]]: a[1]}))));
    }

    var result = [];
    iter(object.aggregations, []);
    return result;
}

var data = { took: 562, timed_out: false, _shards: { total: 5, successful: 5, failed: 0 }, hits: { total: 4812178, max_score: 0, hits: [] }, aggregations: { publisher: { doc_count_error_upper_bound: 0, sum_other_doc_count: 3114671, buckets: [{ key: 4, doc_count: 1697507, advertiser: { doc_count_error_upper_bound: 0, sum_other_doc_count: 555390, buckets: [{ key: 5, doc_count: 1142117, country: { doc_count_error_upper_bound: 13807, sum_other_doc_count: 544585, buckets: [{ key: "us", doc_count: 424137, revenue: { value: 772282 }, cost: { value: 53698.84903321415 } }] } }] } }] } } };

console.log(getValues(data));
```

Comment: This works. Do you know if there's a way to get this output straight from elasticsearch?

Comment: @Franci, i am sorry, i don't know ES.